# Configure Windows Firewall Server 2008 to allow access by only selected IP addresses

Tags: windows, firewall, streaming, media

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 and I need to configure the firewall if possible to only allow access from a few specified IP addresses, any other IP addresses will get rejected unless accessing via port 80, where any IP address can access a website.

It is because I am using NCH Broadcam streaming media server, and currently Port 86 streams the media from the servers IP address (e.g. 1.2.3.4:86) - so I want any access to the server at port 86 to only stream media to whitelisted IP address - any non whitelist IP's will get nothing on port 86.

thanks.

Comment: List the firewall rules you have in place.

Answer (score 1):

Setup an inbound firewall rule and set these settings:

- *Protocols and Ports* list the port(s) number
- *Scope* tab list the Remote IP addresses you will allow the
  connection from
- Make sure the rule applies to the appropriate profiles: Domain,
  Private, or Public
- Ensure you have permissions, if you need any, under the *Users* tab
- Restart the Firewall service after creating the rules

*Inbound* rules handle other machines accessing your computer. Since you are running a server you have to tell the Firewall that outsiders are allowed to connect to it.
*Outbound* rules determine which programs are allowed to use the Internet and it blocks others.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have tried this and still all IP's accessing port 86 were allowed through (?)

Comment: Would it be an Inbound or Outbound rule?

Comment: Inbound. Edited the answer.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am using Broadcam media server, and I have tried creating the Inbound/Outbound rules so that only users coming from one specific IP address can access the media content that is streamed to their device, but regardless of having the in/out firewall rules (windows 2008 server) and ip address coming in can access the streaming media so i am stuck!

Answer (score 0):

probably no one needs this anymore, but it seems that for it to work as slybloty described, it'll need to have Public profile enabled. Otherwise it won't work as intended.